# how to automatically load data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a windows service, and `html+j` query page to consume a web service.
When a Document is scanned in our device, I want to load: name, country, and Passport number to our web page.
I already append these details in my web page, but I want to load these details in a text box. [image]

```html
<th>Passport No: <input type="text" id="initialize" value="d.get.DocumentNumber"/>
<th>Disable:<input type="text" id="disable"/>
<th>Country:<input type="text" id="initialize1"/>
<input type="button" id="documentButton" value="Document"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick example for your reference.

use jQuery selector using `#` for id and `.` for class by appending the id or class name and pass the value into `val` function.

```
$('#initialize').val('Test');
```